# How to match two condition on same string to get one output using regex

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-4.0

I have a string in which I have to find PNR number. To get PNR number I have to check two condition:

> First in Passenger should be more than one.
>
> Second String contain ITINERARY REBOOKED.

If both condition met then extract only the PNR number from the string otherwise return nothing.

My code in which i fullfill my first condition.

```
public DataTable GetPnr(List<string> request) // Here we create the function for get pnr.
{
    dt.Columns.Add("PNR", typeof(string));
    foreach (string data in request)
    {
        string item = data;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        if (item.ToLower().Contains("itinerary rebooked") || item.ToLower().Contains("itineraryrebooked")) // Condition for operated by cases
        {
            Regex regexs = new Regex(@"(\s[A-Z0-9]{6}\s{2})"); // Regular operation for PNR.
            foreach (Match m in regexs.Matches(item))
            {
                output = m.ToString(); // Here we store the PNR value in output string variable.
            }
            dr["PNR"] = output;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Now the thing when I use regex to chech for multiple passenger in the same regex which i use in my function is doesn't return me any output

here is my string for which i want both condition to be checked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> YMT1 = new List<String>();
    string ymt = @"RT29WHVE
                                                            
RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            WS/SU   6MAY13/0503Z   29WHVE //29WHVE is the PNR number                
NYC1S21DD/9525GY/6MAY13                                                         
  1.KHOON/FRANCIS   2.MEH/SAY   3.MEH/PRAY   4.MEH/MAW                          
  5.REH/LAW   6.REH/PAE   7.REH/DO   8.REH/LEE   9.REH/HEH                      
 10  US 152 T 12MAY 7 GEGPHX HK9   300P 534P 12MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 11  US 184 T 12MAY 7 PHXLAS HK9   815P 923P 12MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 12  US 392 K 13MAY 1 LASCLT HK9   115A 827A 13MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 13  US4286 K 13MAY 1 CLTFAY HK9   955A1050A 13MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 OPERATED BY SUBSIDIARY/FRANCHISE                                           
 14 MIS 1A HK9 NYC 11JAN-THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS                            
 15 AP NYC9103161516                                                            
 16 APE FRANCISKHON@GMAIL.COM                                                   
 17 TK OK06MAY/NYC1S21DD//ETU 
 FXR                                                           
 01 KHOON/FRANC*                                                                
 ITINERARY REBOOKED                                                             
 LAST TKT DTE 06MAY13 - SEE ADV PURCHASE  ";

     string ymt2 = @"RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            UA/RM   6MAY13/0452Z       298BFB                
 NYC1S21DD/9999WS/6MAY13                                                        
 1.BELIEU/KENNETH E(ADT)   2.BELIEU/RUTH J(ADT)                               
 3  UA 646 Q 22JUN 6*PDXORD HK2   603A1150A 22JUN  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 4  UA1735 Q 22JUN 6*ORDBWI HK2   115P 409P 22JUN  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 5  UA 209 S 01JUL 1*BWIIAH HK2   545A 800A 01JUL  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 6  UA 258 S 01JUL 1*IAHPDX HK2   856A1120A 01JUL  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
)>FXR                                                                                
01 BELIEU/KENNE*                                                               
NO REBOOKING REQUIRED FOR LOWEST AVAILABLE FARE                                
LAST TKT DTE 07MAY13 - SEE ADV PURCHASE";

    string ymt3 = @"RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            WS/SU   6MAY13/0509Z   Y33ORG //Y33ORG is the PNR number               
NYC1S21DD/80948W/6MAY13                                                        
1.CORTES RIVERA/MARIA(ADT)                                              
2  UA1162 W 21JUN 5*BQNEWR HK6   150A 545A 21JUN  E  UA/GW176R               
3  UA1209 W 21JUN 5*EWRLAX HK6   700A 955A 21JUN  E  UA/GW176R               
4  UA 398 V 17JUL 3 LAXEWR HK6  1040A 705P 17JUL  E  UA/GW176R        ";       

    YMT.Add(ymt);
    YMT.Add(ymt2);
    YMT.Add(ymt3);  
    Split sp = new Split();
    DataTable dt = sp.GetPnr(YMT); 
}
```

According to my code i take all those PNR which contain ITINERARY REBOOKED but i also want if i have only one pax with ITINERARY REBOOKED then it won't fetch that PNR number
like in ymt3 i have ITINERARY REBOOKED condition but only one pax so i dont want to take PNR number

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
 public DataTable GetPNR(List<string> Request)  // Here we create the function for get pnr.
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("PNR", typeof(string));

        foreach (string data in Request)
        {
            string item = data;
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.[a-zA-Z]\S(.+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(item))
            {
                name = m.ToString();
            }

            if((item.ToLower().Contains("itinerary rebooked") || item.ToLower().Contains("itineraryrebooked"))&&name!=null) // Condition for operated by cases
            {
                Regex regexs = new Regex(@"(\s[A-Z0-9]{6}\s{2})"); // Regular operation for PNR.
                foreach (Match m in regexs.Matches(item))
                {
                    output = m.ToString(); // Here we store the PNR value in output string variable.
                }


            }
            dr["PNR"] = output;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Thanks mate but regex you have given me is used for both multiple as well as single passenger i need a regex which fetch only muliple passenger and avoid single passenger